# ¿Cómo cambiar mi código c a c++?

Tags: c++, dev-c++

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
```

¿Cambiarían las librerías que tiene el código?

```
struct colas{
char clave[100],nc[100],nom[100];
double sueldo;
int tiquete;
struct colas *sig;
};
struct colas *read=NULL,*front=NULL;

void menu();
void dentrar();
void boletas();
void pasar();
void calculo();
```

Este código que tengo que esta hecho en C, ¿qué cambia para poder hacerlo en C++?

```
main()
{


menu();

return 0;
}


void menu()
{
int n,esta,opcc;

for(int i=0;;i++)
{
esta=0;
printf("\n");
printf("\t BANCO BASS \n");
printf("1. PASAR AL CLIENTE AL BANCO\n");
printf("2. PASAR AL CAJERO \n");
printf("3. SALIR\n ");
printf("OPCION: ");
scanf("%d",&n);
```

En el switch, se podría poder igual en c++?

```
switch(n)
{
case 1:dentrar();break;
case 2:pasar();break;
case 3:if(!front)
esta=1;
else
{


printf("TODAVIA QUEDAN CLIENTE\n");
printf("1. DESEA CONTINUAR ATENDIENTO CLIENTES \n");
printf("2. CERRAR SOFTWARE\n");
printf("OPCION: ");
scanf("%d",&opcc);
if(opcc==2)
esta=1;
}
break;
}
if(esta)break;
}

}
void dentrar()
{
char s;
int mirar;
struct colas *a,*b;
a=(struct colas*)malloc(sizeof(struct colas));
printf("\tINFORMACION DEL CLIENTE\n");
printf("NOMBRE: ");
gets(a->nom);
gets(a->nom);
printf("CLAVE: ");
gets(a->clave);

b=read;
s='S';

do{
mirar=0;
printf("NUMERO DE CUENTA: ");
```

la función `gets` también cambiaría?

```
gets(a->nc);
if(read)
{
while(b)
{
if(!(strcmp(b->nc,a->nc)))
{
printf("\tYA EXISTE\n");
getch();
mirar=1;
break;
}
b=b->sig;
}
}
if(mirar==0)
s='N';
}while(s=='S');


printf("SUELDO: ");
scanf("%lf",&a->sueldo);
printf("NUMERO DE TICKET: ");
scanf("%d",&a->tiquete);

if(!read)
{
a->sig=NULL;
read=front=a;
}
else
{
a->sig=read;
read=a;
}
return;
}

void pasar()
{
struct colas *q;
int bol,o;
if(front)
{
for(int i=0;;i++)
{
if(!front)break;
printf("\tCAJERO DE SERVICIO\n");
printf("1. SEGUIR\n");
printf("2. CANCELAR\n");
printf("OPCION: ");
scanf("%d",&o);
if(o==1)
{
printf("NUMERO DE TICKET A SEGUIR ES [[ %d ]]\n",front->tiquete);
printf("SU NUMERO DE TICKET: ");
scanf("%d",&bol);
if(bol==front->tiquete)
calculo();
else
{
q=read;
while(q)
{
if(q->tiquete==bol)
{
printf("\tLO SIENTO POR FAVOR ESPERE SU TURNO\n");
printf("EL TICKET QUE SIGUE ES %d\n",front->tiquete);
getch();
break;
}
q=q->sig;
}
if(!q)
{
printf("\tLO SIENTO NO EXITE EL CLIENTE\n");
getch();
}
printf(" ");

}
}
else
break;
}
}
else
{
printf("\tNO HAY NINGUN CLIENTE\n");
getch();
printf(" ");
}
return;
}

void calculo()
{
struct colas *d;
int opc,apro=0,c;
double re;
char cla[100],con;
printf("\tEJECUTAR PROCESO\n");
printf("EL SALDO DEL CLIENTE %s ES %.0lf\n",front->nom,front->sueldo);
printf("1. RETIRAR\n");
printf("2. CONSIGNAR\n");
printf("3. NADA\n");
printf("OPCION: ");
scanf("%d",&opc);
gets(cla);
printf("\tANTES DE EJECUTAR LA OPERACION POR FAVOR INGRESE \n");
c=3;
do{
printf("CLAVE: ");
gets(cla);
if(!(strcmp(cla,front->clave)))
apro=1;
else
{
printf("\t%d OPORTUNIDADES\n",c);
getch();
printf(" ");
c--;
printf(" ");

}

}while((c>=0)&&(!apro));

if(apro)
{
apro=0;
c=3;
do{
printf("NUMERO DE CUENTA: ");
gets(cla);
if(!(strcmp(cla,front->nc)))
apro=1;
else
{
printf("\t%d OPORTUNIDADES\n",c);
getch();
printf(" ");
c--;
printf(" ");
}
}while((c>=0)&&(!apro));
}

if(apro)
{
switch(opc)
{
case 1:while(1)
{
printf("SALDO DEL CLIENTE %s ES %.0lf\n",front->nom,front->sueldo);
printf("¿CUANTO DESEA RETIRAR? \n");
scanf("%lf",&re);
if(re>front->sueldo)
{
printf("NO SE PUEDE RETIRAR, **FONDOS INSUFICIENTES**\n");
getch();
printf(" ");
printf("DESEA CONTINUAR <S><N> : ");
printf(" ");
con=getche();
if(toupper(con)=='N')break;
}
else
{
front->sueldo=front->sueldo-re;
break;
}
}
printf("NUEVO SALDO DEL CLIENTE %s ES %.0lf\n",front->nom,front->sueldo);
getch();
break;
case 2:while(1)
{
printf("SALDO DEL CLIENTE %s ES %.0lf\n",front->nom,front->sueldo);
printf("CUANTO DESEA CONSIGNAR: ");
printf(" ");
scanf("%lf",&re);
if(re<0)
{
printf("NO EXISTE ESA CANTIDAD\n");
getch();
printf(" ");
printf("DESEA CONTINUAR <S><N> :");
con=getche();
if(toupper(con)=='N')break;
}
else
{
front->sueldo=front->sueldo+re;
break;
}
}
printf("NUEVO SALDO DEL CLIENTE %s ES %.0lf\n",front->nom,front->sueldo);
getch();
break;
case 3:
printf("\tGRACIAS POR SU ATENCION\n");
getch();
break;
}
}
else
{
d=read;
while((d->sig!=front)&&(d!=front))
d=d->sig;
if(d==front)
{
printf("\tLO SIENTO ACCESO DENEGADO POR NO COINCIDIR CON LA INFORMACION\n");
printf("\tCOMO NO HAY MAS CLIENTES NO SE ATIENDE MAS\n");
getch();
printf(" ");
printf(" ");
}
else
{
printf("\tLO SIENTO ACCESO DENEGADO POR NO COINCIDIR CON LA INFORMACION\n");
printf("\tPOR FAVOR EL SIGUIENTE ES CON EL TICKET %d\n",d->tiquete);
getch();
printf(" ");

printf(" ");
}
}
d=read;
while((d->sig!=front)&&(d!=front))
d=d->sig;
if(d==front)
front=read=NULL;
else
{
front=d;
d=front->sig;
front->sig=NULL;
}
free(d);
return;
}
```

Toda la estructura que tiene el código, cambiaría?

> Cita en bloque

Answer (score 4):

Todo lo que has puesto compila perfectamente tanto en C como en C++ así que si lo que te importa es simplemente migrarlo... felicidades, ya lo has conseguido!!! Para compilarlo en C++ simplemente tienes que usar un compilador de C++ y listo.

Ahora bien, si lo que quieres es que el código se beneficie de las bondades y disgustos de C++ podrías implementar cambios como los siguientes:

## Librerias

En C++ las librerías estándar **no llevan extensión**. Las heredadas de C pierden igualmente su extensión y, para distinguirlas un poco más, reciben el prefijo `c`:

**`C`**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
```

**`C++`**

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
```

¿Es este cambio importante? Generalmente sí. Esta versión de las librerías puede incluir las funciones dentro del espacio de nombres `std`, lo que ayuda a organizar mejor el código y las funciones.

## Entrada/salida

C++ dispone de objetos específicos para gestionar la entrada salida. Las utilidades que rodean a estos objetos hacen que, generalmente, el código sea más legible y expresivo.

Así, `printf`, `puts` y demás pasan a ser absorvidos por `std::cout`, mientras que `scanf`, `gets` y compañía pueden ser reemplazados por `std::cin`.

**`C`**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int numero;
printf("Dime un numero: ");
scanf("%d", &n);
printf("Has elegido el numero %d\n", n);
```

**`C++`**

```
#include <iostream>

int numero;
std::cout << "Dime un numero: ";
std::cin >> numero;
std::cout << "Has elegido el numero " << numero << '\n';
```

## Cadenas de texto

Cuando queremos manejar texto en C no nos queda otra que usar `char*` o `char[]`, estructuras con muchas limitaciones y complejas de usar:

- En ambas hay que tener cuidado de no escribir / leer fuera de los límites del array
- Con `char*` hay que manejar memoria dinámica... peligro de fugas de memoria
- `char[]` no admite redimensionado... muy restrictiva

En C++ tenemos el objeto `std::string` que viene a reemplazar a estas dos estructuras. Al ser una clase dispone de multitud de utilidades que permiten escribir código más legible:

**`C`**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char nombre[500];
char buffer[500];
puts("Dime tu nombre: ");
scanf("%s", nombre);

puts("Dime tu apellido: ");
scanf("%s", buffer);

strcat(nombre, buffer);
printf("Bienvendio %s\n", nombre);
```

**`C++`**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string nombre;
std::string apellido

std::cout << "Dime tu nombre: ";
std::cin >> nombre;

std::cout << "Dime tu apellido: ";
std::cin >> apellido;

nombre += apellido;

std::cout << "Bienvenido " << nombre << '\n';
```

## Clases y objetos

En C no existe el concepto de clase. Lo más parecido son las estructuras de datos y únicamente sirven para *estructurar* y agrupar las variables que tenemos que usar en nuestros programas.

Sin embargo C++, al estar orientado a objetos, le da una nueva vida a las viejas estructuras de datos de forma que las mismas pasan a ser más útiles:

- Admiten constructores: Permiten inicializar sus variables automáticamente durante la construcción del objeto
- Admiten destructores: Los recursos se pueden liberar de forma automática.
- Los atributos pueden ser privados: Mejora el encapsulamiento
- ...

Además, como pequeña gran ventaja, no hace falta usar `struct` al declarar variables:

**`C`**

```
struct colas{
  char clave[100],nc[100],nom[100];
  double sueldo;
  int tiquete;
  struct colas *sig;
};
```

**`C++`**

```
struct colas{
  std::string clave;
  std::string nc;
  std::string nom;

  double sueldo;
  int tiquete;
  colas *sig;

  colas() // Constructor por defecto
    : sig(nullptr) // Inicializamos el puntero `sig`
  { }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola las librerías están bien pero yo pasaria de conio.h, el método main seria un:

```
int main(){
    menu();
}
```

puedes cambiar los scan, get/getch y printf por los cout y cin de

```
#include<string> //Esta es valida en C++
```

puedes revisar el estandar [C++ estandar](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header) para revisar el resto del código

en cuanto a tu switch tambien es legal en C++, no reescribo el código porque voy de salida pero con esto te puedes guiar para escribir tu código en C++